# .htaccess is redirecting to original URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have following .htaccess file and i am trying to rewrite URL **www.example.com/play/tribe-test** instead of **www.example.com/love/tribe-world/tribe-test**.

Now when i am hitting **www.example.com/play/tribe-test** its redirecting me to **www.example/love/tribe-world/tribe-test** which is original URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^play/(tribe-test.*)$ /love/tribe-world/$1 [L] // This rule is getting redirected to original URL

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(we-are-stereotribes.*)$ /love/tribe-world/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(for-the-lovers.*)$ /love/tribe-world/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(for-the-campaigners.*)$ /love/tribe-world/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(for-the-funders.*)$ /love/tribe-world/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(terms-of-use.*)$ /love/tribe-world/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(privacy-policy.*)$ /love/tribe-world/our-support/$1 [L,QSA]

# prevent httpd from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
RedirectMatch 403 /\..*$
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.css|\.js)$
#RewriteRule ^theme/anther/?  sthemes/anther/index.html 
RewriteRule !html|\.(pdf|php|js|ico|txt|gif|swf|jpg|png|css|rss|zip|tar\.gz)$ index.php
```

will highly appreciate your help

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes url is also getting changed to /love/tribe-world/tribe-test

Comment: /love/tribe-world is directory and tribe-test is my page name..

Comment: I don't see any rule here using `R` flag so redirection from above rules is not possible. Is there any other .htaccess in your system?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65255/discussion-between-anubhava-and-kalpit).